# Viewing Data From a Table To Modal Using PHP

Tags: php, modal-dialog

I am using a table to retrieve all the data from the database and an array of view button on each table row. If the view button is clicked, a modal will appear displaying all the information of the particular row.

The problem is that the only id read is the last id. Giving the same view results for each table row.

I have this line of code in the view button:

```
< button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-viewaccountinfo">View< / button>
```

While  my modal code is this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-viewaccountinfo" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title"><center>USER ACCOUNT INFORMATION</center></h3>
          </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" action="">
        <br>

        <?php
        $id = $_GET['txtid'];
        include ("connect.php");
        $i ="select * from usersvis where userid=".$id;
        $h= mysql_query($i);
        if($tr=mysql_fetch_array($h))
        {
    ?>
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    Name:
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <label type="text"><?php echo $tr[3] . ' ' . $tr['4'] . ' ' . $tr['2']; ?></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    Username:
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <label type="text"><?php echo $tr[5]; ?></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    Password:
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <label type="text"><?php echo $tr[6]; ?></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    Gender:
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <label type="text"><?php echo $tr[7]; ?></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    Birthdate:
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <label type="text"><?php echo $tr[8] . '-' . $tr['9'] . '-' . $tr['10']; ?></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    Address:
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <label type="text"><?php echo $tr[11]; ?></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    Status:
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <label type="text"><?php echo $tr[12]; ?></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: use `while` not `if`.

Comment: Sir the while loop is giving me a notice saying  "undefined index: txtid . . ." and a warning saying "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource . . ." Why is that? @Fred-ii-

Comment: where is the `$_GET['txtid']` coming from?

Comment: Sir, it's coming from my login.php file. I put it in the header location: 

header("Location:adminmainpage.php?txtid=$result[0]"); 

@Fred-ii-

Comment: My query is this:

    $sqll = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `userid`,`email`, `firstname`, `usertype`, `status` FROM `usersvis` WHERE `email` = '$username'");  

      while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sqll))
      {

Comment: You're using mysqli_ functions in ^^^ but in your posted code you have a few `mysql_` functions; those don't intermix with mysqli_.

Comment: make sure you didn't use the same `mysql_` connection; you need to use `mysqli_` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php should that be the case. Edit: you deleted the comment I was replying to.

Comment: Sir I've already changed it to mysqli_ but  it didn't work. It only gave me another warning saying "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be resource . . ." but when I use mysql_, it works yet the only id being retrieved is the last ID displaying the same information in each view button  clicked. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Oh Sir I'm sorry I've just edited it yet I don't have the privilege to save it that's why I just re-comment it.